# Optimize Sieve of Eratosthenes for big numbers in Python

Tags: python, performance, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm solving [Euler exercise number 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) and trying to go a bit further on bigger primes.
It is too slow with big numbers. I've been reading ways to optimize the sieve, but I would like to ask people with more experience with this.

```
import time
from math import log, ceil

start = time.time()
primes = [2]
op_count = 0
limitN = 0
pr_count = 0

def primes_goto(prime_index):
    global primes
    global op_count
    global limitN
    global pr_count

    if prime_index < 6:
        limitN = 100
    else:
        limitN = ceil(prime_index * (log(prime_index) + log(log(prime_index)))) #bound

    not_prime = set()

    while pr_count < prime_index:
        for i in range(3, limitN, 2):
            if i in not_prime:
                continue

            for j in range(i*3, limitN, i*2):
                not_prime.add(j)

            primes.append(i)
            pr_count += 1

    return primes


ind = int(10001)
primes_goto(ind)
ind_prime = primes[ind-1]

end = time.time()


print("Prime number at posizion: {} = {}".format(ind, ind_prime))
print("Runtime: {}".format(end-start))
```

Comment: What big numbers have you tried and what is the expected performance? By the way, 1 is not prime.

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=7

Comment: I've tried to calculate the 1000000 prime number, and it took 5 seconds

Comment: Python is very slow, if you care about optimised performance you would write in C/C++, which is roughly 20x-100x faster than python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unused variables

`op_count` is declared in the global scope, pulled into the `primes_goto` local scope, but is never used.  It may be deleted.

## Unnecessary Globals

`limitN` and `pr_count` are declared in the global scope, but only ever used inside the `primes_goto` function.  They may be removed from the global scope, and simply declared inside the `primes_goto` function.

## Unused Return

The `primes_goto` function ends with `return primes`, but the returned value is not assigned to anything.

One way to fix this would be to remove the `return primes` statement.

A better way would be to move the `primes = [2]` initialization inside the `primes_goto` function, and remove `global primes` declaration.  Then, return this local result, and assign the result to a variable in the caller’s context.  Ie)

`primes = primes_goto(ind)`

## Unnecessary cast

`ind = int(10001)`

The value `10001` is already an integer; there is no need to “cast” it.

## Organization

Python programs should follow the following organization:

- imports
- function & class declarations
- mainline

The initialization of variables should be moved from before `primes_goto` to after all function declarations.

## Profiling

`time.time()` has limited resolution, due to it expressing the time from an epoch decades in the past, in factions of a second.  `time.perf_counter()` expresses time from an arbitrary epoch to the highest resolution available, making it ideal for measuring time intervals.

## Reworked code

```py
import time
from math import log, ceil

def primes_goto(prime_index):

    primes = [2]
    pr_count = 0

    if prime_index < 6:
        limitN = 100
    else:
        limitN = ceil(prime_index * (log(prime_index) + log(log(prime_index)))) #bound

    not_prime = set()

    while pr_count < prime_index:
        for i in range(3, limitN, 2):
            if i in not_prime:
                continue

            for j in range(i*3, limitN, i*2):
                not_prime.add(j)

            primes.append(i)
            pr_count += 1

    return primes


start = time.perf_counter()

ind = 10001
primes_goto(ind)
ind_prime = primes[ind-1]

end = time.perf_counter()

print("Prime number at position: {} = {}".format(ind, ind_prime))
print("Runtime: {}".format(end-start))
```

## Optimization

### bitarray

As pointed out in other reviews, `bitarray` can be efficiently used to store the sieve flags, and `i*i` is a better starting point for crossing off prime candidates due to all smaller multiples already being eliminated as multiples of smaller primes.

### Avoid unnecessary work

Again, as pointed out in other answers: marking off primes candidates as `3*i` (or `i*i`) is pointless once `i` exceeds `limitN//3` (or `isqrt(limitN)`), you can gain efficiency by separating the prime your `while` loop into two: the first part crossing off multiples of a prime number while adding that prime to the `primes` list, the second `while` loop just adding discovered primes to the `primes` list.

## PEP 8

The Style Guide for Python Programs enumerates several rules that Python programs should follow.  The main violation in your code relates to naming: You should use only `snake_case` for variables.  `limitN` should be renamed to `limit_n`, or `upper_limit`.

## Naming

Why we’re talking about names, `ind`, `ind_prime`, `pr_count` and `prime_goto` are all terrible names.  You might know what they mean today, but other programmers reading the code will have a hard time trying to elude their meaning; you may even have problems if you revisit the code months down the road.

`first_n_primes(n)` would be a better function name.  I’ll leave you to come up with better variable names.

Comment: Nice review,  I didn't point those issues out cause I felt the OP needed just performance review.

Comment: @theProgrammer The OP **wanted** a performance review.  They **needed** a full code review.

Comment: @theProgrammer I actually struggled between upvoting and downvoting your answer.  From the help centre: "_Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"  Your answer was dangerously close to just being an alternate solution.  In the end I decided that the "consuming all free memory (6GB)" was enough of an insightful observation to allow the answer to stand, and instead added my own review.

Comment: thanks @AJNeufeld for the review

Answer (score 1):

You can make this part a bit faster:

```
            for j in range(i*3, limitN, i*2):
                not_prime.add(j)
```

Better start at `i*i`, and better don't do your own loop. So it becomes:

```
            not_prime.update(range(i*i, limitN, i*2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bitarray`, this tends to be a little faster.

The code using `bitarray` is

```
from bitarray import bitarray
import time 
from math import sqrt, ceil, log

def primes_goto2(index: int):
    prime_up_to = ceil(index * (log(index) + log(log(index)))) + 4
    primes = bitarray(prime_up_to)
    primes.setall(True)
    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    primes[4::2] = False
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(prime_up_to)), 2):
        if primes[i]:
            primes[i * i::i] = False
    
    prime_list = [i for i in range(len(primes)) if primes[i]]
    return prime_list[index]
```

Time taken for `1000000` (NOTE: my index does not require index - 1, so in order to get same value as me you have to use `1000001`)

```
index = 1000000
t0 = time.perf_counter()
prime_number = primes_goto2(index)
t1 = time.perf_counter()

print("Prime number at position: {} = {}".format(index, prime_number))
print("Runtime: {}".format(t1-t0))
```

Output:

```
Prime number at position: 1000000 = 15485867
Runtime: 1.888874288000011
```

Which is very much better than yours.

I also noticed, yours consumes a lot of memory, running `1000001` ate up all my free memory(6gb)

Comment: You should use `isqrt()` instead of `int(sqrt())`, especially for large numbers, where floating point accuracy will corrupt the result.  You've got an off-by-one error, since range is half-open.  You want `isqrt(prime_up_to)+1`.

Comment: Using `2*i` for step will increase your speed: `primes[i*i::2*i] = False`

Comment: this solution, with suggestions implemented, took only 0.76 secs, which is dramatically better than mine